# JavaScript random BigInt

Tags: javascript, performance, random

**Problem:** JavaScript does not provide a random BigInt so there is a need to generate a random BigInt within a given range that is evenly distributed.

**Solution**
I have tried many algorithms with a emphasis on speed. The best solution builds an array of random Int32 converted to string and padded with zeros which are then joined converted to a BigInt with the return being `BitInt % range`

```
function randBigInt2(range) { // returns BigInt 0 to (range non inclusive)
    var rand = [], digits = range.toString().length / 9 + 2 | 0;
    while (digits--) { 
        rand.push(("" + (Math.random() * 1000000000 | 0)).padStart(9, "0"));
    }
    return BigInt(rand.join("")) % range;  // Leading zeros are ignored
}
```

As `Math.log` can not be used to get the number of digits in `range` I am forced to use a hack of converting `range` to a string and using the string length to get log<sub>10</sub>

The generated array of digits is at least 9 digits longer than the required `range` to counter the problem of bias to numbers that end in digits less than the least significant digit. Though the bias still exists, it is so small that I am unable to detect it in any tests.

If the range is a multiple of 10 there is no bias

The alternative function that uses BigInt in the calculation is about 2-4% slower.

```
function randBigInt(range) {
    var rand = 0n, digits = range.toString().length / 9 + 2 | 0;
    while(digits--) {
        rand *= 1000000000n;
        rand += BigInt(Math.random() * 1000000000 | 0);
    }
    return rand % range;
}
```

Are there any flaws in my logic?

Comment: I'd use the entire meaningful part of Math.random - at least 15 digits are guaranteed by IEEE754 spec.

Comment: @wOxxOm Unfortunately BigInt math in JS is SLOW.. Using `rand += BigInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e15));` 40% fewer iterations and will increase performance for small ranges by 50%. Its even at 1e140 and 20% slower at 1e1500. Also tried `rand += BigInt(Math.trunc(Math.random() * 1e15));`  BigInt will not convert if there is a fractional component. Using the string `Math.random().toString()` gives 15 digits but will shorten the notation if it can eg 1e-14 so add overhead and thus nit worth it.

Comment: I haven't done research in that regard, but I wonder if using `Crypto.getRandomValues()` with a `BigUint64Array` would be more efficient for very large numbers.